# When does the dragon deck shuffle?

Tags: dungeonquest

I have the Revised Edition of Dungeon Quest.  I remember playing the original edition, and the dragon deck automatically shuffles if there are no heroes inside the treasure chamber.

But I can't find anything in the revised rules for when the dragon deck shuffles.  Reading the "Dragon Rage" card, it seems the deck shuffles whenever someone draws that card and waked the dragon.  In the original version, drawing that card forced everyone out of the treasure chamber, and *that* caused the deck to reshuffle as a side effect.

So in the revised edition, does the dragon deck shuffle when there are no heroes in the treasure chamber?  Or only when someone is unlucky enough to wake the dragon?

Answer (score 1):

The deck is only shuffled when the card instructs you to do so.

This way it's semi-guaranteed that the Dragon will eventually wake up. With the " shuffle when there are no heroes in the treasure chamber" rule the Dragon could potentially never wake up - the heroes could reset his "timer" by leaving and re-entering the chamber.

Comment: Any official rules text or at least other sources? The game does have the day tracker already to limit turns. And how do you account for the discrepancy with the original version of the game?

Comment: I used the "Rules Reference" and "Learn to Play" documents available on FFG site. The text are pretty short, but I have searched through both of those for all instances of "shuffle" and "dragon" to make sure I haven't missed anything.
The reference doesn't say anything about shuffling the Dragon Deck (except at the beginning of the game when you shuffle all the decks).
If it doesn't say you shuffle, then you don't shuffle.
If the only place where it instructs you to shuffle is on the dragon card, then it's the only situation in which you shuffle.